# información de ultimas fechas

Tags: oracle, sql

```
SELECT id, descw, part,serial  
FROM parts 
INNER  JOIN  brow 
ON TO_CHAR(id_sw) = TO_CHAR(id) 
AND codigo = 33  WHERE (id = 2
OR id =4 OR id =6 
OR id =8 )  
AND serial = 'XXXXXXXX');
```

--

```
id 2 = decw
id 4 = part
id 6 = serial
```

Estos códigos pertenecen a cada una de las columnas e información que se estará consultando.

En mi consulta la cual funciona perfectamente, estoy obteniendo los datos de `descw`, `part` y `serial` ademas del `inner join` estos datos se obtienen del código `33`
despues de poner el serial del cual necesitamos la información, traera cada uno de estos. Tengo un problema
Necesito la informacion de acuerdo a las ultimas fechas, esto se calcularía con la siguiente columna `date` de la tabla `parts`

Donde y como puedo añadir este paso?

Comment: ¿Que quieres decir con respecto a "de acuerdo a las últimas fechas"? ¿Quieres ordenar por esta columna? ¿Quieres obtener las que sean de los últimos días?

Answer (score 0):

puedes agregar un order by date DESC al final

```
SELECT id, descw, part,serial  
FROM parts 
INNER  JOIN  brow 
ON TO_CHAR(id_sw) = TO_CHAR(id) 
AND codigo = 33  WHERE (id = 2
OR id =4 OR id =6 
OR id =8 )  
AND serial = 'XXXXXXXX')

order by  parts.date DESC
;
```

si lo que quieres obtener la ultimas fechas agrega
ROWNUM <= cantidad_de_registros